# C++ unordered_map or unordered_set : What to use if I wish to keep an "isVisited" data structure

Tags: c++

I want to keep a data structure for storing all the elements that I have seen till now. Considering that keeping an array for this is out of question as elements can be of the order of 10^9, what data structure should I use for achieving this : `unordered_map` or `unordered_set` in C++ ?

Maximum elements that will be visited in worst case : `10^5`

`-10^9 <= element <= 10^9`

Comment: If you want to store some information about visited element (for example, the time of visit), `unordered_map`. Otherwise (want to store just whether visited or not), `unordered_set`.

Comment: A mapping and a set are two completely different in semantic sense structures. You should choose based on whether you *just need to store elements somewhere* and *need to have a mapping from some type to another type*.

Comment: a bitset of 10^9 bits, one bit per `isVisited` value, would take just 125MB, and the access would be much faster if the node indices are contiguous. You could achieve that with either `std::bitset` if the size is known during compilation, or `std::vector<bool>` if it's not. Though I would avoid `std::vector<bool>` and roll my own specialized solution, as vector of bool has weird semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeCAT said in the comments, a map would only make sense **if you wanted to store additional information about the element or the visitation**. But if you wanted only to store the truth value of whether the element has been visited or not, the map would look something like this:

```
// if your elements were strings
std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> isVisited;
```

and then this would just be a waste of space. Storing the **truth value is redundant**, if the mere presence of the string within the map already indicates that it has been visited. Let's see a comparison:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> isVisitedMap;
std::unordered_set<std::string> isVisitedSet;

// Visit some places
isVisitedMap["madrid"] = true;
isVisitedMap["london"] = true;

isVisitedSet.insert("madrid");
isVisitedSet.insert("london");


// Maybe the information expires so you want to remove them
isVisitedMap["london"] = false;
isVisitedSet.erase("london");
```

Now the elements stored in each structure will be:

```
For the map:
{{"london", false}, {"madrid", true}} <--- 4 elements
{"madrid"} <--- 1 element. Much better
```

Answer (score 0):

In a project in which I had a binary tree converted to a binary DAG for optimization purposes ([GRAPHGEN](https://github.com/prittt/GRAPHGEN)) I passed the exploration function a map from node pointers to `bool`:

```cpp
std::map<BinaryDrag<conact>::node*, bool> &visited_fl
```

The map kept track of the pointers in order not to go through the same nodes again when doing multiple passes.

You could use a `std::unordered_map<Value, bool>`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to keep a data structure for storing all the elements that I have seen till now.

A way to re-phrase that is to say "I want a data structure to store the **set** of all elements that I've seen till now". The clue is in the name. Without more information, `std::unordered_set` seems like a reasonable choice to represent a set.

That said, in practice it depends on details like what you're planning to do with this set. Array can be a good choice as well (yes, even for billions of elements), other set implementations may be better and maps can be useful in some use cases.